# Tomcat Two-Way SSL trust specific certificate only without importing the CA certificate

Tags: tomcat, truststore

i have some problem with tomcat's two-way ssl connection,

I need to set up a web service that is using a two way ssl connection.
there will be two different certificate used, one for ssl connection and one for soap signature.
The rule is, the certificate used for soap signature, cannot be used on ssl connection, and vice versa.

the client has three certificate,
the ssl certificate, the soap certificate, and the their own CA certificate that sign their ssl and soap certificate.

the problem is on the ssl connection, when i import only the client's ssl certificate to tomcat's custom trusttore specified on tomcat's configuration file, the connection threw a ssl bad certificate exception. but when i tried to import only the CA certificate, ssl connection using SOAP certificate was also accepted by tomcat, breaking the rule.

what confused me was, when i didn't specify any custom truststore file -- which i assume that tomcat will used the default cacerts file -- without importing any client certificate to the cacerts file, the connection was accepted by tomcat. how is this possible? i have set the "clientAuth" to "true" on tomcat's configuration.

can anybody helps me?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Look at this (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Installing_a_Certificate_from_a_Certificate_Authority). What essentially needs to be done is to import your CA root certificate (as SSL cert is signed by the root)& SSL certificate  into the key store and configure the key store for SSL on tomcat (the above document details the steps). This should take care of your SSL problem.

Now, coming to the SOAP issue, SOAP related signatures are essentially XML Signatures and Tomcat does not handle the same. These signatures follo wthis specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-dsig/), which is essentially an extension. The SOAP service implementation, for instance Apache CXF handles these signatures (refer: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html). Though you may not be using CXF, the server library actually will do this signing using certificates that you provide (the store for this certificate is another matter).

As for the last part of your question, check if the request was made using SSL, Tomcat usually will not accept SSL requests on 443/8443 unless a certificate is configured.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. i have tried that, but the problem is, when i import the CA certificate, ssl connection using SOAP certificate, which is forbidden by the rule, is accepted by Tomcat. I Just dont understand what is the function of importing a client certificate to tomcat's truststore (not keystore) if we still need to import the CA certificate that signed it too.

Comment: @rucciva, the Tomcat does not have a trust store of its own, by default it used javax.net.ssl.trustStore, which usually points to JVM trust store. SSL has provision to ask for client's certificate as well during handshake but is usually not used/enabled. In your case, possibly you have imported CA cert into JVM trust store and have enabled client certificate for SSL. Now in SSL, if a client provides a certificate and it can be validated against CA cert, then the client identity is established, so the SOAP cert will also work for client side ... cont

Comment: Do this, for a test, do not set the value for trustStoreFile for Tomcat SSL configuration (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html)and only have the SSL cert and CA cert in Tomcat 'Key Store' and check. Next set clientAuth value to false i.e. disable client auth. and check.

Comment: it says here (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) that we can set tomcat's truststore file by specifying the 'truststore' option. i have tried to omit the truststore option in tomcat's configuration file but without importing any of client certificate (not the CA too). but the ssl connection is also accepted. does it mean that the certificate provided by client can be verified by the default CAs on jvm truststore? so is it imposible for tomcat to trust the client on two way ssl by importing only client's ssl certificate, without the client's CA certificate?

Comment: You will find the default CA certificate in the file 'cacerts' in JDK_PATH\jre\lib\security, try taking the file out of that folder and check once, technically since no CA certificates are present, JVM should not be able to verify it and should throw an exception (or not). But do this on a box where you an reinstall the JDK if necessary. In addition, there could be more than one JRE on your box (but Tomcat would be using the one inside the JDK). This is a bit of different kind of problem, so you may have to do some tial & error - :)